# how to remove tags of a specific class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

i am parsing a HTML page using Beautifulsoup (python3.x)
i am trying to get data from < p> tags for which i have written

```
def getBody(url):
    html_page = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page.content, 'html.parser')
    Con = "".join([p.text for p in soup.find_all("p")])
    #print(Con)
return Con
```

but in doing so i am getting text from the below htmltag. How can i remove this?

`<p class="notice">Comments are closed for this article.</p>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**`decompose()`**](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#decompose) or [**`extract()`**](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract) to remove tags.

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = '''
... <p>text</p>
... <p class="notice">Comments are closed for this article.</p>
... <p>text</p>
... <p class="notice">Comments are closed for this article.</p>
... <p>text</p>'''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
>>> for tag in soup.find_all('p', class_='notice'):
...     tag.decompose()
...
>>> soup

<p>text</p>

<p>text</p>

<p>text</p>
```